# MVC Routing Access

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I would like to know whether this can be done in MVC.

Lets say we have customer order entry of

Customer ID  - 1
Order ID  - 2

Let's say when user types /Order/View?id=2
I would like this page can be accessible to customer who has ID 1 **only**. Let's assume we keep this ID in identity.

Is there easy way to achieve this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult View(){
    var userName = User.Identity.Name;  
    var id = Request["id"];  
    if (userName == "1" && id == "2")
        return RedirectToAction("Authorized");
    else
        return RedirectToAction("Unauthorized");
}
```